# Convergent subsequence under image of adjoint.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces, and let $T : X \rightarrow Y $ be a bounded linear operator, and denote by $T^*$ the adjoint operator of $T$.

Suppose also that $X$ is separable, that is, $X$ admits a countable dense subset. Let $ (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N} } $ be a sequence of bounded linear functionals in $Y^*$. Prove that if $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ is bounded, then $ T^*(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ has a convergent subsequence.

Quite stuck on this, any hints or tips?

Comment: You're correct, my mistake.

Comment: What is $g_n$ and what have you tried?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem

Comment: As stated, this is wrong but $T^*(g_n)$ has a weak$^*$-convergent subsequence (use daw's hint to Alaoglu and metrizability of the dual unit ball of $X$ in the weak$^*$-topology).